# Overriding class property via class declaration

Tags: c++, oop

Question is not easy to describe by several words in title. So, i've a some manager who managed of some type objects implement by user. Object can be 2 types, for example - positive and negative. So i want to get user set this options via class declaration. Obvious way:

```
class Base;
class BasePositive : Base;
class BaseNegative : Base;

class UserObject1 : public BasePositive;
class UserObject2 : public BaseNegative;
```

Fine, it's worked well. But if we want to use inheritance:

```
class UserObjectBase : public BasePositive;
class UserObject3 : public UserObjectBase;
```

Ops, all derived classes from UserObjectBase can be only Positive. I want to get user reliable mechanism to declare own classes and set type of positive or negative (for example). So, i've search some mechanism to override some field/property in base class (no matter what it is - just achieve it).

Really, i didn't see any solution without macros. But may be somebody else known?

C++11 - extensions can't be used (i want, but can't).

**UPDATE:**

With virtual inheritance i've some success:

```
#include <iostream>

struct base {
    ~base() {}
    int value;

    bool isPositive;    
};

struct pos : virtual base {
    pos() {
        isPositive = true;
    }
};

struct neg : virtual base {
    neg() {
        isPositive = false;
    }
};

struct foobase : pos {};
struct fooNeg :  virtual foobase, virtual neg {};
struct fooPos : foobase {}; 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{ 
    fooNeg f;
    std::cout << f.isPositive << "\n";
    fooPos p;
    std::cout << p.isPositive << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But virtual inheritance is bad practice as i known. Looking something else ...

Answer (score 1):

Could it be you are looking for pure virtual function?

```
class Base {
public:
  enum Polarity { POSITIVE, NEGATIVE };
  virtual Pole polarity() const = 0;
};
```

This forces users to declare if their class is either positive or negative and would still leave a choice further down the hierarchy.

Comment: No, i don't want to enforce user implement virtual function. It's are not reliable.

Comment: Because, user have many own classes - too many oneline functions, possible mistake, just miss overwrite virtual function and object have invalid type. My goal to exclude it and move to class declaration.

Comment: @Torsten If a pure virtual function is not overriden, the given code would not compile. I call that comparatively safe.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you want to express a 'has-a' relationship with an 'is-a' technique?

At first sight, it seems that all user classes 'have-a' polarity.  Expressing this attribute through (single) inheritance is awkward, and indeed leeds to the problem you have: the user has to choose whether a class contains positive or negative values, although his subclasses could be both.

Multiple inheritance as [suggested by Joachim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12348900/6610) could be a technique to achieve a succinct way to express the  polarity of a user class, but most of the time I used it, it brings more bad than good.  Do read [Meyers' article on that](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill07.htm); at least, make it private!

Maybe inheritance is just not a clean solution for this problem.  [Pmr's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12348882/6610) hint also points in that direction.  Imagin the scalability issues arising when you add another discriminating attribute e.g. discrete/continuous, high/low, ...

Your client's code may become more verbose than you would like, but at least, you aren't forced into a class explosion!

Comment: The article is actually written by Herb Sutter, not Meyers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that C++ can handle multiple inheritance, so you could use separate base classes and combine them. Something like:

```
class PosNegBase;
class Positive : public PosNegBase;
class Negative : public PosNegBase;

class UserObjectBase;
class UserObject3 : public UserObjectBase, public Positive;
class UserObject4 : public UserObjectBase, public Negative;
```

Comment: @xtofl For this case I agree, as polarity is an attribute of an object and not distinct concept.

Comment: Seems it's worked if use virtual inheritance. But virtual inheritance is bad practice.